# Match Column values of a dataframe with another dataframe with a column containing comma seprated values using grepl

Tags: r

I am trying to lookup and match two data frame (df1 & df2) by matching a column (val) on each data frame, the first data frame column contains text value but on the second data frame (df2) column contains multiple text values separated by comma, here is the view of the data frames

```
val=c("AAAA","XXXX","BBBB","YYYY","ZZZZ","MMMM","YYYY","CCCC","GGGG")
df1 <- as.data.frame(val)
```

```
val=c("AAAA,BBBB","BBBB,CCCC,FFFF","CCCC,DDDD,GGGG,FFFF","GGGG","")
id =c(1,2,3,4,5)
df2 <- as.data.frame(val,id)
```

if the value of df1 is found in df2 then I need the id on the new column in df1

Answer (score 0):

See whether the below code helps.

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 = df2 %>% 
  mutate(val=str_split(val, ",", n=Inf)) %>% 
  unnest

df1 = df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="val")
```